# Renaming a variable in a Python code in MS VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have defined a variable `T_0` at the top of a python code, and want to change this variable by `F2` of MS VS Code.

```
T_0 = 10
T_1 = T_0 + 1
print(T_1)
```

But first, I got an error message `Refactoring library rope is not installed`.

Then I found an answer to this at [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/613). After appropriately changed this, I got a new error message `Refactor failed. Rename refactoring should be performed on resolvable python identifiers.`.

How can I rename a variable in a python code on MS VS Code?

I am using Python 3.6, VS Code 1.19.2.

Comment: I just tested this with VS Code Insiders and the in-development version of the extension and it worked for me. Are you using the latest version of rope?

Comment: Other solution: install Pylance extension ([see more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59570939/14522024))

Answer (score 4):

It is confirmed as a problem with rope 0.10.7

This link shows how this error is connected to rope https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2094

and this link shows that the issue with rope is still unresolved as of 2020 April 2 
 https://github.com/python-rope/rope/issues/249

Answer (score 2):

This is not a fix for the bug mentioned in Ben's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61115516/2853530), but it did fix the issue for my project and configuration:

- Visual Studio Code 1.51.1
- Python 3.8.5
- rope 0.18.0
- venv

The issue was not with my project's code but code inside the *.venv* subdirectory that rope also tried to examine. There is a config file for rope in vscode, located at *.vscode/.ropeproject/config.py* in my case, and inside:

```py
def set_prefs(prefs):
    prefs['ignored_resources'] = ['*.pyc', '*~', '.ropeproject',
                                  '.hg', '.svn', '_svn', '.git', '.tox']
```

Adding `'.venv'` to the array made rope skip that directory and rename refactor started working. Admittedly, there were still cases I found where it would not catch uses of a name and failed to rename things without warning, which leads me to not trust the function.

Comment: Installing rope 0.18.0 solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried several solutions and solved it. However I didn't know which one worked actually. **You can refer my methods but they may not work for you.**

1. I found there were two `rope` packages installed in my conda environment (python3.6), one for python3.6 and another for python2.7. In fact, after I uninstalled one `rope` package, I found it still existed with another version number. It was really strange. So I uninstalled them all and re-installed it with conda (or pip).
2. The extensions `python` and `Visual Studio IntelliCode` may be not compatible. Because auto-completion didn't work for me and it worked again after I uninstalled the latter.
3. Re-install vscode and all its extensions completely.