# vscode python refactor failed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I tried to rename `myset` in the following code, I saw the following message.

```
class NumberGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__myset__ = set()

    def uncount(self, i):
        self.__myset__.add(i)
```

```
Refactor failed. module 'rope.base.ast' has no attribute 'Str'
[<FrameSummary file refactor.py, line 294 in watch>, <FrameSummary file refactor.py, line 274 in _process_request>, <FrameSummary file refactor.py, line 206 in _rename>, ...
```

It's so long, if you want to see I can show you. Is this code wrong? It works, though. Why does refactor not work?

Answer (score 23):

It doesn't work because Rope has some bugs in it. If you install [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) then you may have better success (it will automatically prompt you to update your settings appropriately).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I sure that by you.

Comment: I switched to Microsoft, but it doesn't have resymbol function anymore.

Comment: @UniSize try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance

Comment: @BrettCannon Do you know what the difference between the python package developed by Microsoft and the one you mentioned in the last comment? They all developed by Microsoft.

Comment: @UniSize the link/Pylance is the new one, MPLS is the old one. I find Pylance faster and more accurate, so I would advise switching to it.

Comment: @BrettCannon I see this is python language server, what is the default python server we get? will installing this affect my interpreter(or anything) anyhow?

Comment: The default is Jedi, but I would recommend [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance).

Comment: Pylance is really useful. Working perfectly on VSCode and Win 10 WSL.